# `phonegap build android` faild. exit log says, "Command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I am trying to execute the phonegap build android command, but it is giving me an error. I need it to create an apk file to send push notifications to it. I have created a new project and when I execute the command I get the following error.

> Downloading
>   http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
>
> ```
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
>
> ```
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
>
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
>     ... 3 more
> ```
>
> C:\Users\anuraag\PhoneGapProjects\phonegapDemo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                       ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\anuraag\PhoneGapProjects\phonegapDemo\platforms\android\gradlew
>   cdvBuildDebug -b
>   C:\Users\anuraag\PhoneGapProjects\phonegapDemo\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
>
> Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c
>   "C:\Users\anuraag\PhoneGapProjects\phonegapDemo\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat"
>
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with
>   exit code 1 You may not have the required environment or OS to build
>   this project
>
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\anuraag\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:139:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

**What I feel is the problem?**
I think that phonegap is not being able to download gradle from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip as the .gradle folder is empty.

**Why I can't resolve it and a possible solution?**
I have read many answers for similar problems but none of the resolved my error.
I am not behind any proxy and have temporarily disabled my firewall and anti-virus. But still I've frequently encountered problems of connecting to servers in eclipse and android sdk.Generally by doing a manual install I was able to overcome them.

I have ran phonegap build android before, I am assuming the problem started when phonegap updated to support gradle. So i was wondering if I can manually the files needed and populate the .gradle folder.

Comment: You have installed and configured the entire development environment for Android (SDK )? See - http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/installing/index.html - This could solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have set up the sdk properly

Comment: @user3420463 you are correct. This is because your gradle did not install well.  I made some minor corrections to your post. Which platform are you working on? Windows, OSX, Linux? Are you working with an IDE? Eclipse, Android Studio, Visual Studio?

Comment: I am working on a windows machine, I have android studio installed. Even if I try to reinstall gradle it doesn't work. Somethimg prevents the CLI to reach the server(I can reach it using the browser).

Comment: Can I manually add the .gradle folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem was running the command setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true and updating the sdk libraries and then running phonegap build android